# How to add "DRAFT" along the left/right margin?

Tags: draft, draftwatermark

The `draftwatermark` package emblazons "DRAFT" across a page or pages. The intention appears to be to ruin a document to make it unusable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{draftwatermark}
% \SetWatermarkLightness{0.8}
\SetWatermarkScale{4}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum{1-5}
\end{document}
```

[image: draft-emblazoned]

But what if the intention is just to ward against accidental use of a preliminary document by a sleep-deprived individual, without jarring so much or interferring at all with the readability of the text.

Adding "DRAFT" along the left/right margin would do the trick. Is there a package for that?

**Update**

The selected solution is heavy-handed, because it uses `tikz`, which interacts poorly with simple `\begin\end{verbatim}` formatting. ("Package tikz Error: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of...").

A lighter solution, one that 1- uses an existing lighter package, and 2- cohabits with many other packages (geometry, perhaps even memoir, ...) without issues, would be nice.

Comment: `background` does it easily.

Comment: That's a suitable more general solution. I'm having trouble though with the output of both draftwatermark and background packages. It seems that Preview on OS X (Mavericks) does not show their added marks, just the text itself. Debugging...

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: ok.. debugging consisted of noticing the big red exclamation mark in the documentation for background :) . It reads "The document needs to be processed twice to get the background material in the right position." Indeed, just adding "\usepackage[placement=bottom]{background}" in the preamble (and processing **twice**) does it. I'd prefer a minuscule running "draft" continuous mark along the right margin, but this is a good start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compile more than 3 times.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
  position=current page.east,
  angle=-90,
  nodeanchor=east,
  vshift=-5mm,
  opacity=1,
  scale=3,
  contents=Draft
}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This gives me "! Package xkeyval Error: `nodeanchor' undefined in families `background'." Upgrading to TeX Live 2014 (from 2013), just in case.

Comment: @Calaf Upgrading should solve it. Any way, you won't need `nodeanchor` with `vshift` as in this code.

Comment: Upgrading to 2014 indeed solves the problem.

Comment: How could one put one of these in each margin, in the interests of symmetry? I tried adding a similar stanza for the west. And it does indeed appear in the west, but the one in the east disappeared.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: You have to detect the odd and even pages and then put the text accordingly. Search for `\ifodd`...

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to patch this command. Here a code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{draftwatermark}
%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sc@watermark{%
  \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.1\paperwidth}% change here as you need horiz pos
  \setlength{\@tempdimc}{-.5\paperheight}%  change vertical pos
  \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){%
    \makebox(0,0){\rotatebox{\sc@wm@angle}{%
        \scalebox{\sc@wm@scale}{%
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\textcolor
          \expandafter\sc@wm@colormodel\expandafter{\sc@wm@colorspecs}{%
            \fontsize{\sc@wm@fontsize}{1.2\sc@wm@fontsize}
            \selectfont
            \sc@wm@text}}}}}}
\makeatother
% \SetWatermarkLightness{0.8}
\SetWatermarkScale{4}
\SetWatermarkAngle{90}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: touhami / Steven: it seems this can be done using a 1- or 2-liner with the background package. Using "\usepackage{background}" followed by "\backgroundsetup[contents=foobar,placement=bottom,color=blue]" in the preamble produces an error "! Package xkeyval Error: `[' undefined in families `background'." Debugging...

Comment: background is better.

Comment: I can't see the problem with xkeyval. Asked a separate question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231330/9549

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I concocted for another application, though it is at top and bottom, not left and right.  However, since your intention is "just to ward against accidental use of a preliminary document by a sleep-deprived individual," it may be sufficient.  It can be turned on/off easily, changed, color added, etc.  Syntax is `\PageStamp[]` (default "DRAFT") and `\StopPageStamp`, along with `\def\PageStampColor{}`.

Its also set up to use `\thispagestyle{\PlainStyle}` or `\thispagestyle{\EmptyStyle}` to handle using the page stamp with or without page numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\makeatletter
%%
%% SET UP CODE TO USE PAGE STAMPS AT TOP AND BOTTOM OF PAGE.  DEFAULT
%% STAMP IS "DRAFT", BUT IT CAN BE USED FOR CLASSIFICATION MARKINGS.,
%% TOO.
\def\PageStampFlag{F}
\def\thePageStamp{}
\def\thePageStampTOP{\thePageStamp}
\def\EmptyStyle{empty}
\def\PlainStyle{plain}
\def\PageStampColor{black}

\newcommand{\ps@pagestamp}{
  \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\sffamily\color{\PageStampColor}%
                           \hfil\textbf{\Large\thePageStampTOP}\hfil}
  \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}
  \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\sffamily\hfil
                            \begin{tabular}{c}
                            \textrm{\thepage}\\
                            \color{\PageStampColor}
                            \textbf{\Large\thePageStamp}
                            \end{tabular}
                            \hfil}
  \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\@evenfoot}
}

\newcommand{\ps@emptypagestamp}{
  \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\sffamily\color{\PageStampColor}%
                             \hfil\textbf{\Large\thePageStampTOP}\hfil}
  \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}
  \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\sffamily\hfil
                            \begin{tabular}{c}
                            ~\\
                            \color{\PageStampColor}
                            \textbf{\Large\thePageStamp}
                            \end{tabular}
                            \hfil}
  \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\@evenfoot}
}
\newcommand\PageStamp[1][DRAFT]{
  \def\PageStampFlag{T}
  \def\thePageStamp{#1}
  \def\PlainStyle{pagestamp}
  \def\EmptyStyle{emptypagestamp}
  \pagestyle{\PlainStyle}
}

\newcommand\StopPageStamp[0]{
  \def\PageStampFlag{F}
  \def\PlainStyle{plain}
  \def\EmptyStyle{empty}
  \pagestyle{\PlainStyle}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\PageStamp[DRAFT \today]
\lipsum[1-7]
\StopPageStamp
\lipsum[8-13]
\def\PageStampColor{red}
\PageStamp[This is a Test]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]